# How to customize kendo-grid-checkbox-column?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Here is my demo,

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukx3gf)

What I want is put a check box and a text together. In the demo link,

it is

[image]

But I don't want to hard code string `Select row`. I want to replace it with the field. For example, Product Name. So the expected result is Chai then checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution, using dataItem

Here is the trick.

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
         {{dataItem.ProductName}} <input [kendoGridSelectionCheckbox]="idx" />
       </ng-template>
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukx3gf